# Collections in java - how to choose the appropriate one

Tags: java

I'm learning about collections and trying to ascertain the best one to use for my practice exercise.....I've done a lot of reading on them, but still can't find the best approach.....this may sound a bit woolly but any guidance at all would be appreciated....

I need to associate a list of Travellers, with a list of Boarding Passes. Both classes contain a mutable boolean field that will be modified during my programme, else all other fields are immutable. That boolean field must exist. I'll need to create a collection of 10 travellers, and then when all criteria has been met, instantiate a boarding pass, and associate it with them.

There won't be any duplicates of either due to each object having a unique reference variable associated with them, created through an object factory.

From doing some reading I understand that Sets must contain immutable objects, and don't allow duplicate elements, whereas Lists are the opposite.

Because I need to associate them with each other, I was thinking a Map, but I now know that the keys are stored in a set, which would be problematic due to the aforementioned reasons....

Could I override the hashcode() method so that it doesn't taken into consideration the boolean field and therefore as long as all of my other fields are immutable it should be fine? Or is that bad practice?

I also thought about creating a list of Travellers, and then trying to associate a Boarding Pass another way, but couldn't think of how that could be achieved....

Please don't give me any code - just some sort of a steer in the right direction would be really helpful.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but: can't you use the unique references (ID's) as keys? Sidenote: what data structures to use depends a lot on how you'll use your data. Lots of retrieval/insertion/deletion?

Comment: If you are using a `HashMap` or `HashSet` you **must** override `equals` and `hashCode` to provide meaningful object equality. The is no restriction on either of these collections that requires immutability. But if you mutate a field used to define equality, the result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BoristheSpider unless reference equality is the behavior you want.

Comment: @JBNizet I would argue that using an `IdentityHashMap` would be better in that case - it makes it obvious to all when is happening.

Comment: @keyser:I'll have frequent retrieval/insertion/deletion of boarding passes as my travellers will be moving around frequently-FYI, only one traveller can have one boarding pass at any one time. I was thinking I'd need to create a set of travellers, create a hashmap (@Boristhespider - I'll take a look at IdentityHashMap), then add the set of keys with null values, use put() to associate a boarding pass with a traveller, remove() when their journey is finished, and then run a search for the boarding pass value when I need to reassign it to another key/Traveller??

Comment: I can't seem to figure out if a List or Set would be better but I can't see how to associate values without a Map?? I just always see a Map as having fairly fixed key, value pairs whereas mine will alter frequently.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a best practice, you need to think what you are planning to do with the data now and in the (near) future. When you know
what this is, you need to check which of the methods (list, set and map) works best for you. If you want to compare the three, have a look [here](http://java67.blogspot.nl/2013/01/difference-between-set-list-and-map-in-java.html)

Comment: Thanks - I'd taken a look at that already, but still confused! I can't see any other way to associate a Boarding Pass with a Traveller if all Travellers were stored in a List, so I can't see any other way than to use a Map

Answer (score 0):

You've been mislead about the mutability requirements of set members and map keys.

When you do a lookup in a `HashMap`, you do it based on the key's `hashCode`. If you have mutable objects as keys, *and mutating the object modifies the `hashCode` value*, then this is a problem.

If a key was inserted into the table when it had a `hashCode` of `123`, but later it's modified to have a `hashCode` of `345`, you won't be able to find it again later since it's stored in the `123` bucket.

If the mutable boolean field does not influence your `hashCode` values (e.g., you didn't override `hashCode` or `equals` on your key class), then there's no issue.

That said, since you say you'll only have one unique instance of each passenger, Boris's suggestion in the comments about using an [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) is probably the way to go. The `IdentityHashMap` gives the same behavior as a `HashMap` whose keys all use the default (identity-based) implementations for `hashCode` and `equals`. This way you'll get the expected behavior whether or not you've overridden `equals` and/or `hashCode` for other purposes.

(Note that you need to take equality into account as well as the hashCode.)

Comment: Thanks so much @DaoWen - The HashMap is starting to become clearer, and this is really comprehensive, I'm just not sure that a HashMap is the best way to go. Can you see my comments above? Woukd you mind giving your opinion on those?

Comment: @javapalava - *"I just always see a Map as having fairly fixed key, value pairs whereas mine will alter frequently."* HashMaps offer fast updates as well as fast lookups. In fact, updates have the same theoretical complexity as lookups. It's definitely well-suited for frequent updates.